# git - How do I undo a merged pull request into master

Tags: git, github

I merged an approved pull request into my master branch by mistake. The PR was supposed to be for a develop branch that I'm using whilst i build my app. I then did a revert of the PR into the develop branch but now it has overridden the code that was in before. I had already merged 2 PR's into the develop branch before this.

How do I undo the merge into my master back to its initial commit and also reset my develop branch back to the previous merged PR?

Comment: Can you carefully describe each chain of events, one by one?  This is hard for me to follow.  My guess: you were on an unknown branch (not `develop` - call it `foo`) and merged into `foo` into `master` (was `foo` based off of `develop`?) - then you did a revert of the PR into the `develop` branch (wasn't `foo` merged to `master`?) and it overrode code that was in `develop` (isn't this what's supposed to happen during a revert?).  Can't you revert `foo`'s merge commit on master, and then pull the latest master code?

Comment: if pull request was branched out of dev and merged into master then you're kinda out of luck... because there's usually a huge difference between master and dev branches

Comment: I created a new feature branch based off my develop branch. I then made a commit and pushed to github. Made a pull request but accidentally made it to be merged into master instead of develop. My mentor approved my PR and I merged. I then realised that I had merged into master by mistake. I then thought I could revert the PR into develop and it would fix this. It made a new branch and merged that into develop but now there is no code showing in develop just the readme file.

Comment: Master was clean only had the initial commit before the merge

Answer (score 1):

this is how merges are

```
master    a..b..c..d...f...h...j..... 
pullreq              e...g...i..../
```

when they merge it becomes

```
master:   a..b..c..d..e..f..g..h..i..j..
```

now you want to remove pullreq changes, so in that case you can do is

```
git checkout d
git checkout -b newmaster
git cherry-pick f
git cherry-pick h
git cherry-pick j
```

where a,b,c,d,e etc are commits.

not a very easy task, so be careful when you merge something into master...

There are other ways, but I'll leave'em to someone else!

also if you branched something out of 'dev' branch and merged it into 'master', then you're probably out of luck because now whole dev branch is also merged into master alongwith that pull request. Pray!

Comment: I think your “this is how merges work” is either confusing or wrong. The resulting history usually only looks like that after a rebase, not a merge.